# Cache Inclusion Property- Multilevel Caching

Tags: caching, cpu-cache

I am not able to understand the concepts of cache inclusion property in multi-level caching. As per my understanding, if we have 2 levels of cache, L1 and L2 then the contents of L1 must be a subset of L2. This implies that L2 must be at least as large as L1. Further, when a block in L1 is modified, we have to update in two places L2 and Memory. Are these concepts correct ?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [Can an inner level of cache be write back inside an inclusive outer-level cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59450056/can-an-inner-level-of-cache-be-write-back-inside-an-inclusive-outer-level-cache). Although that one is more recent, but it has better/correct answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, we can say adding more levels of cache is adding more levels of access in memory hierarchy. Its always trade-off between access time and latency. larger the cache, more we can store, but takes more time to search through. As you have said, L2 cache must be larger than L1 cache. otherwise its failing the basic purpose of the same.

Now coming to whether L1 a subset of L2. Its not always necessary. There is Inclusive cache hierarchy and exclusive cache hierarchy. In inclusive, as you said the last level is superset of all other caches.

you can check this presentation for more details
[PPT](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~qitian/CS7123/slides/09-12-2011/talk1-09-12-2011.pptx).

Now updating different levels, is a cache coherence problem & larger the number of levels, larger the headache. You can check various protocols here: [cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence)

Comment: the ppt is invalidate

Comment: Check this https://www.cs.utah.edu/~rajeev/cs6810/pres/12-6810-12.pdf    @scottxiao

Answer (score 3):

You are correct about an inclusive L2 cache being larger than the L1 cache. However, your statement about an inclusive cache requiring a modification in the L1 also requiring a modification in the L2 and memory is not correct. The system described by you is called a "write-through" cache where all the writes in the private cache also write the next level(s) of cache. Inclusive cache heirarchies do not imply write-through caches.

Most architectures that have inclusive heirarchies use a "write-back" cache. A "write-back" cache differs from the write-through cache in that it does not require modifications in the current level of cache to be eagerly propogated to the next level of cache (for eg. a write in the L1 cache does not have to immediately write the L2). Instead, write-back caches update only the current level of cache and make the data "dirty" (describes a cacheline whose most recent value is in the current level and all upper levels have *stale* values). A write-back flushes the dirty cacheline to the next level of cache on an eviction (when space needs to be created in the current cache to service a *conflict miss*)

These concepts are summarized in the seminal work by Baer and Wang "On the inclusion property of Multi level cache heirarchies", ISCA 1988 [paper_link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ed09/3d114bd33a2e897435360e812658e0ac1d46.pdf). The paper explains your confusion in the initially confusing statement:

> A 
>   MultiLevel 
>   cache 
>   hierarchy 
>   has 
>   the 
>   inclusion 
>   property(ML1) 
>   if 
>   the 
>   contents 
>   of 
>   a 
>   cache 
>   at 
>   level 
>   C_(i+1), 
>   is
>   a 
>   superset 
>   of 
>   the 
>   contents 
>   of 
>   all 
>   its 
>   children 
>   caches, 
>   C_i, 
>   at 
>   level 
>   i.” 
>   This 
>   definition 
>   implies 
>   that 
>   the 
>   write-through 
>   policy 
>   must 
>   be 
>   used 
>   for 
>   lower 
>   level 
>   caches. 
>   As 
>   we 
>   will 
>   assume 
>   write-back 
>   caches 
>   in 
>   this 
>   paper, 
>   the 
>   ML1 
>   is 
>   actually 
>   a 
>   “space” 
>   MLI, 
>   i.e., 
>   space 
>   is 
>   provided 
>   for 
>   inclusion 
>   but 
>   a 
>   write-back 
>   policy 
>   is 
>   implemented.

Comment: "Instead, write-through caches update only the current level of cache and make the data "dirty". Shouldn't this be write-back caches?

Comment: +1, it took me a long time to grok that Intel's shared inclusive L3 cache (in Nehalem through Skylake-client) was only tag-inclusive for lines that were Exclusive or Modified in the private caches of individual cores.  So it's a "space MLI" cache according to that paper's terminology.